# Traffic Manager to Load balance Layer 4 traffic between On Prem Physical machines and Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer, azure-traffic-manager, azure-hybrid-connections

Can Traffic Manager be used to load Balance(Active-Active or Active-Passive) Non-HTTP(S) Layer 4 traffic between On Premises and Azure Virtual Machines.

Answer (score 0):

Traffic Manager performs DNS-based load balancing which can be configured to [distribute traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-configure-weighted-routing-method) across endpoints, assuming your on-premises machines are exposed to the internet.

If not, you should instead use Azure Load Balancer with your [on-premises network connected to your Azure VNET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/).

Answer (score 0):

There are three types of endpoint supported by **Traffic Manager**:

- Azure endpoints are used for services hosted in Azure.
- External    endpoints are used for IPv4/IPv6 addresses, FQDNs, or for
  services    hosted outside Azure. Theses services can either be
  on-premises or    with a different hosting provider.
- Nested endpoints are used to    combine Traffic Manager profiles to
  create    more flexible    traffic-routing schemes to support the
  needs of    larger, more complex    deployments.

With ***[priority traffic-routing method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-routing-methods#priority-traffic-routing-method)***, you can set an Active-Active or Active-Passive setup.